# how to transpose few rows to column using awk or sed

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, tr

I want to bring some of the data in a row to the side column of the current column,. Chunk 1 and chunk 2 of the column are separated by a new line. How can I do it.

```
Cat filename
aaa
bbb
ccc
ddd

eee
fff
ggg
hhh


cat desiredFile
aaa eee
bbb fff
ccc ggg
ddd hhh
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways. A simple one using bash, paste, and GNU sed is

```
paste -d ' ' <(sed '/^$/Q' filename) <(sed '0,/^$/d' filename)
```

Here

- `sed '/^$/Q' filename` prints all lines in the file up to the first empty line
- `sed '0,/^$/d' filename` prints all lines after the first empty line
- `<()` is a bash-specific process substitution that expands to the name of a pipe from which the output of the command can be read (so that it can be used as an input filename), and
- `paste -d ' ' file1 file2` pastes two files together in the manner you described (delimited by a space because of `-d ' '`; without that option it would use a tab)

Or you could use awk:

```
awk -v RS="" -F '\n' 'NF > n { n = NF } { for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) a[i] = a[i] OFS $i } END { for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print a[i] }' filename
```

With an empty `RS`, awk splits the file into records at the empty line, with `-F '\n'` it splits those records into fields at newlines, and then the code is

```
# remember maximum number of fields encountered
NF > n { n = NF }

# wade through the fields, assemble the output lines from them
{ for(i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) a[i] = a[i] OFS $i }

# in the end, print the assembled lines.
END { for(i = 1; i <= n; ++i) print a[i] }
```

The advantage of the awk approach is that it'll work with more than two chunks of lines.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby is handy for one-liners, and it has a builtin transpose method. Using a similar approach to Wintermute, we have:

```
ruby -00 -F"\n" -ane '
    BEGIN {data=[]}
    data << $F
    END {data.transpose.each {|row| puts row.join(" ")}}
' file
```

I added another paragraph to the test file, and it outputs this:

```
aaa eee iii
bbb fff jjj
ccc ggg kkk
ddd hhh lll
```

Comment: This is cool. When you have a moment can you explain a bit the options used? I'm especially intrigued by `-00`.

Comment: Ruby stole some ideas from Perl here: the `-0` option sets the record separator to the octal value of option's argument; the `-F` option sets the field separator; and the `-a` option automatically splits the record and stores the fields in the `$F` array. There are 2 special values for `-0`: `777` disables record separation and slurps the input as one single string; `0` splits the input into records on sequences of empty lines, i.e. "paragraphs".

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { numCols=1 }
!NF { numRows=0; ++numCols; next }
{ a[++numRows,numCols]=$0 }
END {
    for (r=1;r<=numRows;r++) {
        for (c=1;c<=numCols;c++) {
            printf "%s%s", a[r,c], (c<numCols?OFS:ORS)
        }
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
aaa eee
bbb fff
ccc ggg
ddd hhh
```